# Error: TARGET_CPU_VARIANT not set?

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm

I am building a C Code to android using ndk in eclipse. I need to include libc library which requires me to set a TARGET_CPU_VARIANT. This is the error message precisely. I am using `armeabi-v7a`. What should I do?

```
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT not set or set to an unknown value.
Possible values are cortex-a7, cortex-a8, cortex-a9, cortex-a15, krait, denver. 
Use generic for devices that do not have a CPU similar to any of the supported cpu variants
```

Comment: TARGET_CPU_VARIANT is used when building Android images, not Android apps. NDK should be used for building apps. Something is probably off with your setup or code base.

Comment: @auselen: Could you help me out in explaining how to build glibc to ndk. I am a newbie and am lost :(

Comment: Just drop the idea, honest advice, I don't know the latest status but building glibc was almost impossible a few years back. that's why people come up with lightweight c libs as well.

Comment: @auselen: Is bionic/libc the way to go about then? thanks

Comment: yes. it should be the way.